# Validate string a+b

Tags: java

I would like to validate if the particular string is `true` or not in form of `a + b`

If `input` = `a + b` true

If `input` = `a +` false

if `input` = `+ b` false

where `a` and `b` can be any string characters

Comment: Put in some efforts buddy and then ask question

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If you don't know where to start, look at the methods in the [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class, and the tutorial on regular expressions (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) for some ideas.

Comment: BTW if you didnt know we compare strings with equal() method

Comment: guys a and b are random characters from user input. I want to check if "random string"+"random string". If there is no string on either side of + sign then return false

Comment: @Lucifer Are `a` and `b` strings or characters? (your last comment contradicts itself on that). Is `+` the character `+` or the `String` concatenation operator?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of ways:

- Use a regex to match a "+" the characters before and after it.
- Use String.indexOf("+") to find a "+" character and test the value of the index to see if it as the start or end of the string.

(Don't forget the cases where `a` or `b` could contain a "+" character; i.e. multiple "+" characters in the string.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression (regex) to test the string. In java you can use the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes to test if a string matches a given regex. The regex you want to use is:

```
String regex = ".* \\+ .*";
```

This regex will test for a string in the following form: "[characters] + [characters]". 
[Here](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-regex) is more information about the regex in java.